# Java; How would I store a persons favorite artist after entering multiple song names and artists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

**Background:** So, I am in an AP Computer Science class in the 11th grade (so you probably know we do not get very advanced). Usually, when we are assigned an assignment I am able to easily understand it and I am also very good at problem-solving when it comes to errors and other things just not working.

**Explanation:** I was assigned an assignment that seemed pretty easy, first you have someone enter a song title then they enter who the song artist is. They do this for as many songs as they want to (meaning it is in a while loop), then it will take the info they entered and put the song names into one ArrayList and the artists into another. After doing so I am supposed to figure out a way to figure out their "favorite artist" meaning if they enter the same artist multiple times it will print that artist as their favorite along with the song next to it.

**Requirements:** Needs to use ArrayLists, cannot contain information that we did not learn during class, cannot use classes and runners, and the print statement has to print out in evenly spaced columns and rows (which I already understood by using formatting and "%-10s %10s %n").

**My Progress:** I am at the point to where they enter all of the songs and I have made two double for loops (a for loop inside a for loop), the first to identify the favorite artist and the second to double-check if there are any other artists in the array. The first double for loop puts the favorite artist into a third ArrayList so that if there are multiple favorites (or an even amount of two artists repeated) then it will have all of them stored. The second for loop is used to remove any artists that did not repeat or repeated fewer times than a different artist so that the only thing in the third ArrayList is the "favorite" and/or the most repeated one.

**The Songs and Artists used in teachers example(Test 1, 2, and 3 are for me to easily see the repeated artists songs):**

```
    1."back in black"
    2."test1"
    3."right now"
    4."test2"
    5."one"
    6."sweet home alabama"
    7."test3"
    8."live and let die"

    1."acdc"
    2."the who"
    3."van halen"
    4."the who"
    5."metallica"
    6."lynyrd skynyrd"
    7."the who"
    8."guns n roses"
```

**My Code:**

```
    import java.util.*;
public class SongArtists {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Favorite = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;

        while (true) {

        System.out.println("Enter song titles #" + count);
        String title = in.nextLine();

        count++;

        if (title.equals("done")) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Who Performs " + title + "?");
        String artist = in.nextLine();

        titles.add(title);

        artists.add(artist);

        for (int i = 0; i < artists.size(); i++) {
              for (int j = i; j < artists.size(); j++) {
               if (artists.get(i).equals(artists.get(j))) {

                   Favorite.add(artists.get(i));

               }
              }
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < Favorite.size(); i++) {
              for (int j = i; j < Favorite.size(); j++) {
               if (Favorite.get(i).equals(Favorite.get(j))) {

                   Favorite.remove(i);

               }
              }
        }

        }

        System.out.println("Your favorite artistss");
        System.out.println("=====================");
        System.out.printf("%-10s %10s %n", "artists", "Song\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < Favorite.size(); i ++) {

            System.out.printf("%-10s %10s %n", Favorite.get(i), titles.get(i));

        }
        }

    }
```

**Console Output:**

```
Your favorite artists
=====================
Artist          Song

the who         test1 
van halen   right now 
metallica       test2 
guns n roses        one
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue/question?

Comment: My question is explained above the code. If you are talking about the title of the post, I didn't have much room for the question/problem, and this problem is not exactly specific to this project as the project is odd and I do not quite understand the problem enough to ask a question so I thought maybe my title was good enough to get a response.

Comment: please read [ask]. You've posted your problem, and your code - but unless you explicitly state: "I want X to happen, but Y is happening instead" it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: Tip of the day: please **give your variables a useful name**. How would anyone know (or you, if you have a large project) what `word`, `word2` is?? Call them what they are: `numSongs`, `artistsList`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off: please use meaningful variable names. `word, word2` are horrible names, may I recommend `title, artist`.

I'm not really understanding the question, but if you want to know how to keep track of the favorite artist I would do 1 of the following:

1. Use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that has a String key and an int value. The key is the artist name and the value is the amount of times the artist appears. Then use a separate String variable called `topArtist` and whenever you add an artist to the map, check to see if that artist appears more than the `topArtist` and if so, overwrite the `topArtist`
2. Use an ArrayList that contains [Pairs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pair-class-in-java/) of  and follow the same logic as above, except whenever you try to add an artist check to see if the ArrayList already contains the artist and if so increase the `int` of the pair by 1.
   Note: method 2 is slower because the `ArrayList.contains()` method is O(n) time complexity

Let me know if that solves your question or if you need clarification!

Comment: Not a bad answer but I am doubtful that they covered Map in class if the OP didn't mention it - so he wouldn't be allowed to use it

Comment: @sleepToken I figured that much, but at least now OP knows a good way to solve this problem if OP encounters it in their future career :)

Comment: I like your answer, a lot actually, but unfortunately we have not learned Map and I don't know if we will. I will also update the code with different variable names for people to better understand, the reason for them was that I was on a tight time gap to get this done and I was kind of rushing the beginning of the project so I had more time to think about the tough parts. Thanks

Comment: @NickWasemiller Sorry to hear that your teacher doesn't want you implementing efficient methods :( I can't stand when professors want the smarter students to lag behind and not self study and learn ahead. If my answer was helpful pls donate an upvote :)

Comment: @RyanRussell Another thing, my program already finds the favorite artist. My main problem is that when it prints, it doesn't put the correct song with the artist. It also prints other artists that were not said more than once which is why I made a remover, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @NickWasemiller Okay, you need to make your problem clear in the question. To find the song associated with an artist I would use a Map<String(artist), String(Songs)> but since you can't use maps I would use Pair<String(artist), String(song)> and then iterate over the ArrayList and print every song from the artist.